# Load website with authentication in a UIWebView

Tags: html, ios, iphone, uiwebview

In my app I've to load a website. To access to this website, I need to send to the server an authentication and I want to show the content of this page in a UIWebView. I'm trying to solve it by using this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    NSString *stringUrl = @"http://54.204.6.246/magento8/acquista";
    [self sendRequestToUrl:stringUrl withMethod:@"GET"];
}

- (id)sendRequestToUrl:(NSString*)URL withMethod:(NSString*)method {
    NSURL *finalUrl;
    if ([method isEqualToString:@"GET"]) {
        finalUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:URL];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Metodo non previsto");
    }
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:finalUrl];
    [request setHTTPMethod:method];
    NSString *authStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", @"user", @"password"];
    NSData *authData = [authStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *authValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", [authData base64EncodedString]];
    [request setValue:authValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
    [request setValue:@"x-www-form-urlencoded charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];

    NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    if (connection) {
        [connection start];
    }
    return connection;
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    recivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [recivedData appendData:data];
}
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[recivedData bytes]]);
    [self.webViewPayment loadData: recivedData MIMEType:@"text/html" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:nil];
}
```

In my `NSLog` I see the HTML of the site and if I paste this HTML to a file and I try to open it I can see the page without problems. Here's the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Acquista</title>
<meta name="description" content="Default Description" />
<meta name="keywords" content="Magento, Varien, E-commerce" />
<meta name="robots" content="INDEX,FOLLOW" />
<link rel="icon" href="http://54.204.6.246/magento8/skin/frontend/default/default/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://54.204.6.246/magento8/skin/frontend/default/default/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var BLANK_URL = 'http://54.204.6.246/magento8/js/blank.html';
    var BLANK_IMG = 'http://54.204.6.246/magento8/js/spacer.gif';
//]]>
</script>
<![endif]-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://54.204.6.246/magento8/skin/frontend/default/default/css/styles.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://54.204.6.246/magento8/skin/frontend/base/default/css/widgets.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://54.204.6.246/magento8/skin/frontend/default/default/css/print.css" media="print" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://54.204.6.246/magento8/js/prototype/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://54.204.6.246/magento8/js/lib/ccard.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://54.204.6.246/magento8/js/prototype/validation.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://54.204.6.246/magento8/js/scriptaculous/builder.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://54.204.6.246/magento8/js/scriptaculous/effects.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://54.204.6.246/magento8/js/scriptaculous/dragdrop.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://54.204.6.246/magento8/js/scriptaculous/controls.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://54.204.6.246/magento8/js/scriptaculous/slider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://54.204.6.246/magento8/js/varien/js.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://54.204.6.246/magento8/js/varien/form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://54.204.6.246/magento8/js/varien/menu.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://54.204.6.246/magento8/js/mage/translate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://54.204.6.246/magento8/js/mage/cookies.js"></script>
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://54.204.6.246/magento8/skin/frontend/default/default/css/styles-ie.css" media="all" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://54.204.6.246/magento8/js/lib/ds-sleight.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://54.204.6.246/magento8/skin/frontend/base/default/js/ie6.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
Mage.Cookies.path     = '/magento8';
Mage.Cookies.domain   = '.54.204.6.246';
//]]>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
optionalZipCountries = ["HK","IE","MO","PA"];
//]]>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
        var Translator = new Translate([]);
        //]]></script></head>
<body class="page-empty  cms-page-view cms-acquista">
    <div>
                        <div class="std"><div style="background-color: #f5f5f5;">
<p><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://oi42.tinypic.com/34gsdcl.jpg" alt="" width="320" height="110" /></p>
</div></div>                    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I try to load the page on the iPhone/iPhone Simulator it shows me an empty page. What's wrong with the code I'm using?

**IMAGE OF WHAT I'M LOOKING AFTER USING THE CODE ABOVE**

You can see here what my simulator is displaying when I try to load the HTML in way Dinesh showed me in his answer and by using my code:

[image]

The site should be something like this:

[image]

Comment: how you are loading the page in simulator?

Comment: both simulator and real device and I'm getting the same result

Comment: Are you loading this page in a UIWebView?Share your code of loading your page..

Comment: I will load this page in an UIWebView. If you look in the method `connectionDidFinishLoading` I'm trying to set data in a UIWebView... Which code I've to share? I already shared the code of the view controller in which I will load the website

Answer (score 0):

In `-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection`

check if your self.webViewPayment has some valid address (should not be nil)

Also if above doesn't work try this

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection function
{
    NSString* respString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[recivedData bytes]];
   [self.webViewPayement loadHTMLString:respString baseURL:nil]; 
}
```

in your .

Comment: How I can see if my UIWebView has a valid address?

Comment: put a breakpoint in your `-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection` and in xcode Debugger window check if self.webViewPayment has null value when it hits the breakpoint..

Comment: I did it and it shows me this (after written `po self.webViewPayment`): `<UIWebView: 0xbe94500; frame = (0 65; 320 365); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0xbe946e0>>`

Comment: I'm sorry but still the same... I tried your new solution but I'm getting this (look to the question)

Comment: Strangely.. I tried your html by copy pasting in a text file here and it doesn't load here as well on UIWebView. Instead i just tried the some headers instead of your html and it loads.. Seems like there is some issue on the HTML and UIwebView is not able to display your html.. YOu can check this yourself..

Answer (score 0):

Note:

This is not going to work:

```
[request setValue:@"x-www-form-urlencoded charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];
```

The MIME type `x-www-form-urlencoded` does not have *any* parameters. So, you *can't* set a charset. Even more, the syntax is invalid. Your server may complain and send you a 400 (bad Request).

Instead use

```
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];
```

AFAIK, there's no way for a client to *specify* the character encoding for form-urlencoded parameters. Usually, the character encoding is given by the server when it returns the form. When the client cannot deduce the character encoding from the form - or when there is no form at all, like in a REST API, the client should use **Unicode UTF-8**.

Curious:  where do you have this malformed content type from?

Comment: still the same... I copied it from other class of my app (in the other class I'm calling a REST API). I put what you suggest me, but when I try to run the app it shows me the same white and black page without content...

Comment: @lucgian841  Well, it's not the same, it's *one error less*. There may be more in your code, though ;)